# Why is the category of fields seemingly so poorly behaved?

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, field-theory

Compared to the categories of other “common” algebraic objects like groups and rings, it seems that fields as a whole are missing some important properties:

- There are no initial or terminal objects
- There are no free fields
- No products or coproducts
- Every arrow is a mono (maybe not a bad thing, but still indicates how restrictive the category is)

A logician once told me in passing that part of the reason is that the properties for fields contain a decidedly “weird” property, namely that every element in a field **except zero** has a multiplicative inverse. If I understood him correctly, this property is sufficiently different from the others that the category of all such objects loses some features. But I have no idea if this was a heuristic or a proven theorem.

Comment: If a zero had an inverse it would not be a zero.

Comment: We're sorry. Really.

Comment: That basically is why, because it implies there can be no nontrivial maps between different characteristics.

Comment: I can think of a way to *test* this in some extremely weak sense. What if you add in the arrows for the ring homomorphisms but *don't* add any additional objects to FIELD? If the category is still non-nice, maybe zero is not to blame.

Comment: @GregoryNisbet You basically don't gain anything: since the kernel of a commutative ring homomorphism is always an ideal, every homomorphism from a ring which happens to be a field is either injective or sends everything to zero. So all that happens is that you add a new "zero morphism" between every pair of fields.

Comment: @NoahSchweber That is, if you are considering non-neccesarily-unital morphisms.

Comment: @JackozeeHakkiuz Good point - if you're looking at morphisms of unital rings, then of course you don't gain any new ones at all.

Comment: Things look a bit better if you look at the category of fields with a given characteristic: you then get initial objects and free objects.

Comment: You don't get free objects (other than the free object on $\varnothing$) – every rational function has a pole somewhere...

Comment: @ZhenLin, setting aside the constants as you obviously meant, [it](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3756136/why-is-the-category-of-fields-seemingly-so-poorly-behaved#comment7726260_3756136) depends on the field, if I understand you correctly.  For example, $1/(x^2 + 1) \in \mathbb R(x)$ has no pole ….

Comment: It doesn't have a pole when evaluated in $\mathbb{R}$, of course, but it does in $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: Fields don't form a variety in the universal algebra sense. By the HSP theorem, this means that fields are not closed under either homomorphic images, or subalgebras, or products (where these are defined relative to total operations of multiplication and addition but not the partial operation of division). This lack of algebraic niceness leads to a lack of categorical niceness.

Comment: Was that logician by any chance Kim Bruce? He told me something very similar back in about 1975 -- that the existence of a negation in the field axioms led to problems of a specific kind (perhaps something like "the homomorphic image of a field is not a field," although I'd have to know what definition of homomorphism was being used for that to make sense...)

Answer (score 57):

There is a precise sense in which the concept of field is not algebraic like, say, the concept of ring or group or vector space etc.: it is a theorem that any kind of mathematical structure that is defined as having a set of elements and some fixed list of total operations of constant finite arity obeying some fixed list of unconditional equations gives rise to a category with certain nice properties (which I omit for the moment). The usual definition of field has a partially defined operation – inversion – as well as an inequality ($0 \ne 1$), which means the theorem is not applicable; the fact that the category of fields does not have the nice properties of algebraic categories tells us there is actually no way of defining fields so that the theorem applies.

So what does being algebraic buy us, and how do we recognise an algebraic category without thinking about the logical form of the definition? Well, a category is equivalent to a category of algebraic structures if and only if it has all of the following properties:

- It has limits for all small diagrams and colimits for small filtered diagrams.
- There is an object $A$ such that the functor $\mathrm{Hom} (A, -)$ has a left adjoint, is monadic, and preserves colimits for small filtered diagrams.

In fact, it follows that such a category has colimits for small diagrams in general, but this fact is not needed in the theorem. Note that the object $A$ is not unique up to isomorphism; this is essentially the phenomenon of Morita equivalence.

Comment: Fancy seeing you here!

Comment: @Asaf For some reason I seem to have too much free time these last few months...

Comment: Could you also add a source for the complete theorem that you mention at the start? Thanks!

Comment: I no longer remember where it is written in the literature. The "only if" direction is easy, at any rate; the "if" direction requires more work but is easy if you know about Lawvere theories, locally presentable categories, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful answer! So then the failure of products, free fields, etc. can all be seen as a failure for certain diagrams to have limits?

Comment: Products are a particular kind of limit. Free objects are what you get by applying the left adjoint of the forgetful functor. It is difficult to reason about counterfactuals but since the category of fields is a finitely accessible category and the forgetful functor is finitely accessible, you could say that if the category had limits then everything would have worked.

Comment: Does the inequality $0\neq 1$ matter so much? Adding the zero ring to the category of fields does not seem to alter the landscape much, since it would be an isolated object anyway.

Comment: There are many (interrelated) reasons for excluding the zero ring. From an algebraic geometry perspective: fields are points, but the zero ring is just empty; from the algebra perspective: the quotient of a commutative ring by an ideal is a field if and only if the ideal is maximal, etc.

Comment: @Brahadeesh You can find this theorem, and a number of related ones, in Adamek-Rosicky-Vitale's book on algebraic theories.